# How can we tracked the time when using Arangosh terminal?

Tags: java, arangodb

I am inserting documents in bulk ~40k documents at one stretch from arangosh. But arangosh does not provide the feature of time taken to execute the command. Is there something to integrate with Arango Shell to track down time (millisec) when executing command ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieved by using JavaScript's built-in `Date` object as follows:

```
/* start time measurement */
var start = Date.now();

/* perform actual operation */
for (i = 0; i < 40000; ++i) { 
  db.collection.insert({ }); /* whatever */ 
} 

/* print elapsed time since start */
print("elapsed time:", (Date.now() - start) / 1000.0, "s");
```